# Read a file relative to a class successor's definition

Tags: python

Say I have an interface class `Base` intended to be inherited. I need to define a static method in `Base` that would read and print a text file next to a successor's definition. My attempt was as follows.

Example structure:

```
.../module/
      __init__.py
      Base.py
      A/
          __init__.py
          A.py
          file.txt
      B/
          __init__.py
          B.py
          file.txt
```

Base.py:

```
import os.path

class Base:
    @staticmethod
    def print_file():
        file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'file.txt')
        with open(file, 'r') as f:
            print(f.read())
```

A.py (same for B.py):

```
from module.Base import Base

class A(Base):
    pass
```

When I import `A` class and call `A.print_file()`, this code attempts to read `.../module/file.txt` and not `.../module/A/file.txt`, as `__file__` seems to be calculated against `Base.py` and not `A.py`.

Is there a way to read `A/file.txt` and `B/file.txt` in the static method without additional code in `A.py` and `B.py`?

Comment: just a guess: use the inspect module, something like: `inspect.getframeinfo(inspect.currentframe()).filename`

Comment: @jojo `print`-ing exactly this line before the rest of the static method prints `.../module/Base.py` when calling `A.print_file()`. Seems like everything is calculated against the base class. Still, thank you, I will look into the inspect module.

Comment: `__file__` will refer to the _current_ file (module) from where it is invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html):

> __file__ is the pathname of the file from which the module was loaded, if it was loaded from a file. The __file__ attribute may be missing for certain types of modules, such as C modules that are statically linked into the interpreter; for extension modules loaded dynamically from a shared library, it is the pathname of the shared library file.

Thus having `__file__` point to Base.py makes sense as this is where the module `Base` initially is loaded from.

An appropriate choice here could be [getfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) from the inspect package:

> *inspect.getfile(object)*: Return the name of the (text or binary) file in which an object was defined.

```
import os
import inspect

class Base:       
    @classmethod          
    def print_file(cls):                                
        file = os.paht.join(
            os.path.dirname(inspect.getfile(cls)),
            'file.txt'
            )  
        with open(file, 'r') as f:
            print(f.read())
```